# VueJS: Transition from dynamic component with :key isn't working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions

I have the following component:

```
<transition name='component-fade' mode='out-in'>
    <component
        :is='marketType'
        :key='market.id'
        :market='market'
        :match='market.match'
    />
</transition>
```

I'm noticing the transition works well the `marketType` has changed, fully changing from different components. However, it is *not* working when the component doesn't change, but the key *does*. Vue seems to be instantly replacing it to be efficient, and ignores the fact that the key has changed.

The [docs show an example of transition between dynamic components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Components) but they don't have examples of both a dynamic component swap + using a key at the same time.

I need the transition to activate when the data changes, regardless of whether the same type of component rendered.

How can I accomplish this?